# Datepicker formatDate

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

i need to change my format date in date picker from "12/25/2022"(for example) on "25/December/2022"

heres my code:

```
$(".date-picker").datepicker({
  format: 'dd-mm-yyyy',
  minDate: 0,
  numberOfMonths: \[3,1\],
  beforeShowDay: function(date) {
    var date1 = $.datepicker.parseDate($.datepicker.\_defaults.dateFormat, $("#input1").val());
    var date2 = $.datepicker.parseDate($.datepicker.\_defaults.dateFormat, $("#input2").val());
    return \[true, date1 && ((date.getTime() == date1.getTime()) || (date2 && date \>= date1 && date \<= date2)) ? "dp-highlight" : ""\];
  },
  onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
    var date1 = $.datepicker.parseDate($.datepicker.\_defaults.dateFormat, $("#input1").val());
    var date2 = $.datepicker.parseDate($.datepicker.\_defaults.dateFormat, $("#input2").val());
    var selectedDate = $.datepicker.parseDate($.datepicker.\_defaults.dateFormat, dateText);

    if (!date1 || date2) {
      $("#input1").val(dateText);
      $("#input2").val("");
      $(this).datepicker();
    } else if( selectedDate < date1 ) {
      $("#input2").val( $("#input1").val() );
      $("#input1").val( dateText );
      $(this).datepicker();
    } else {
      $("#input2").val(dateText);
      $(this).datepicker();
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please see: https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-dateFormat and then: https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#utility-formatDate

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following.

```js
$(function() {
  var dFormat = 'dd/MM/yy';

  $(".date-picker").datepicker({
    dateFormat: dFormat,
    minDate: 0,
    numberOfMonths: [3, 1],
    beforeShowDay: function(date) {
      var date1 = $.datepicker.parseDate(dFormat, $("#input-1").val());
      var date2 = $.datepicker.parseDate(dFormat, $("#input-2").val());
      var result = [true, ""];
      if (date1 && (date.getTime() == date1.getTime()) || (date2 && date >= date1 && date <= date2)) {
        result[1] = "ui-state-highlight";
      }
      return result;
    },
    onSelect: function(dateText) {
      var date1 = $("#input-1").datepicker("getDate");
      var date2 = $("#input-2").datepicker("getDate");
      var selectedDate = $.datepicker.parseDate(dFormat, dateText);

      if (!date1 || date2) {
        $("#input-1").datepicker("setDate", dateText);
      } else if (selectedDate < date1) {
        $("#input-2").datepicker("setDate", $("#input1").datepicker("getDate"));
        $("#input-1").datepicker("setDate", dateText);
      } else {
        $("#input-2").datepicker("setDate", dateText);
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<p>Start: <input type="text" id="input-1" class="date-picker" value="25/March/2022"> End: <input type="text" id="input-2" class="date-picker" value="31/March/2022"></p>
```

The logic in `onSelect` is not clear. I tried to clean it up, yet I cannot determine what you were trying to accomplish.

For `dateFormat`, use `dd/MM/yy`. Breakdown:

- dd - day of month (two digit)
- MM - month name long
- yy - year (four digit)

Details: https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#utility-formatDate

Answer (score 0):

I would like to contribute to this community because it has helped me a lot, so on this occasion, I will share my work related to datepicker. I hope it will be helpful to someone. Datepicker has options to enter, select and move dates forward and backward using the keyboard using the plus and minus keys.

Here is the link:

```
<div style="padding-bottom: 10px; height:25px">
  <label class="labelModalPP">Datum</label>
  <input id="datemask" class="inputModalPP" autocomplete="false" style="position: absolute;left: 100px;height: 20px; width:128px" onkeypress="incrementDate(this.value, 1,event)"/>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/harisba35/pen/jOxWyGm